# Add autocalculate summation row and column in asp.net Listview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, textbox, devexpress

I'm trying to create ListView which contains ASPxTextBox that the user can enter only numeric value. There are many rows and columns of data. I want to add new row and column that calculate total value from each row and column

For example, if I have data like this:

Student Name | Subject1 | Subject2 | Subject3 
----------------------------------------------------------
John ----------- | ------- 23   | --------45 | --------37 
Smith ---------- | ------- 41   | --------22 | --------11 
Linda ---------- | ------- 35   | --------38 | --------23

I want to be like this

Student Name | Subject1 | Subject2 | Subject3 | Total
------------------------------------------------------------------
John ----------- | ------- 23 | --------45 | --------37 | 105 
Smith ---------- | ------- 41 | --------22 | --------11 | --74
Linda ---------- | ------- 35 | --------38 | --------23 | --96
------------------------------------------------------------------
Total----------- | --------99 | -------105 | --------71 | 275

The number of columns (Subject) is fixed but the number of rows depends on data in database.

There are 2 main problems here: 
1. I want the summation row and column to execute calculation in client side using javascript. So when one of textboxes is lost focus, it will recalculate the summation value in each row and column.
2. I can't access the value from ASPxTextBox using javascript. I tried using:

```
var test = document.getElementById('<%# Container.FindControl("txt_Subject1").ClientID %>')
var data = test.value;
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

The following code also cause error:

```
var test = document.getElementById('<%# Container.FindControl("txt_Subject1").ClientID %>')    
var data = test.GetValue();
```

And when I tried ClientInstanceName, it always return the value of the last row only:

```
var data = txt_Subject1.GetValue(); //doesn't work?
```

Also, I don't want to change ASPxTextBox to asp TextBox because I want to use some of its feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dinamically assign ClientInstanceName values based on row number:

```
txt_Subject1_1
txt_Subject1_2
...
txt_Subject1_n
```

Then use javascript to calculate sum:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) 
{
    sum += parseInt(window['txt_Subject1_' + i].GetValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll try this and let you know if it works for my code later.

Comment: Finally, I could get my code works. Thank you so much. You're really a big help :D